# Haskell Type Context from instance declaration required on functions

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I used a type context in doing an instance declaration for a data type I made up.

```
data Set a = Insert a (Set a) | EmptySet

instance (Show a) => Show (Set a) where
    show x = "{" ++ show' x ++ "}" where
        show' (Insert x EmptySet) = show x
        show' (Insert x xs) = show x ++ ", " ++ show' xs

instance Eq a => Eq (Set a) where
    (Insert x xs) == (Insert y ys) = (x == y) && (xs == ys)
```

So now, I have to add the Eq type context to all of the functions I define that use my Set type, like so, or I get a type error:

```
memberSet::Eq a =>a->Set a->Bool
memberSet _ EmptySet = False
memberSet x (Insert y ys)
    | x == y = True
    | otherwise = memberSet x ys

subSet::Eq a=>Set a->Set a->Bool
subSet EmptySet _ = True
subSet (Insert a as) bs
    | memberSet a bs = subSet as bs
    | otherwise = False
```

The error I get looks like:

```
    No instance for (Eq a)
      arising from a use of `=='
    In the expression: (x == y)
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 an equation for `memberSet':
        (x == y)
    In an equation for `memberSet':
        memberSet x (Insert y ys)
          | (x == y) = True
          | otherwise = memberSet x ys
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What does this even mean? Why do I get this error? I figured that once I did the instance declaration, Haskell would be able to automatically verify that the things being compared by "==" in my functions "memberSet" and "subSet" would automatically be checked to be instances of "Eq?"

Edit for clarity:

My issue is that I don't understand why the type contexts are necessary on "memberSet" and "subSet." If I remove them like so, it doesn't compile.

```
  memberSet::a->Set a->Bool
    memberSet _ EmptySet = False
    memberSet x (Insert y ys)
        | x == y = True
        | otherwise = memberSet x ys

    subSet::Set a->Set a->Bool
    subSet EmptySet _ = True
    subSet (Insert a as) bs
        | memberSet a bs = subSet as bs
        | otherwise = False
```

Comment: The code you give typechecks for me. What are you leaving out?

Comment: I suspect some sort of fairly subtle error involving scope or names, since the code as given seems fine.

Comment: My question was unclear. The code as is compiles. I'm wondering why it won't compile with the type context on "memberset" and "subset" I'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your instance declaration says is that `Set a` is an instance of `Eq` whenever `a` is. Whether or not `a` is, in fact, an instance of `Eq` is another matter entirely; this merely allows you to compare two `Set`s with `==`, while in `memberSet` you're only comparing elements.

Consider the type `Integer -> Integer`. This is not an instance of `Eq` for reasons that should be obvious. How would you expect `memberSet` to work if the `Set` contains elements of that type?

I wonder if what you were hoping to accomplish here is ensuring that only `Set`s with an element type that's an instance of `Eq` can be created. If so, that's a very different problem, but also mostly unnecessary--leaving the `Eq` constraint on the functions using `Set`s serves the same purpose in the end.

Why not take a look at [the standard `Data.Set` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html)? Note that most of its functions operating on sets have an `Ord` constraint, reflecting the fact that the internal representation used is a binary search tree.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to familiarize myself with Haskell. I just roughly translated an implementation from SICP. I wasn't trying to accomplish anything in particular. I also left about a bit of code, I wanted to be able to compare sets for equality. That's why it's an instance of Eq. To do that though, I figured all a had to be an instance of Eq

Comment: @Josh: Well then you're in luck, because you are now officially more familiarized with how type class constraints work. :] And yes, comparing two sets requires comparing their elements, so you're correct about that part.

Answer (score 7):

Just for the fun of it, you can arrange it so that the constraints aren't necessary on the functions by using a `GADT`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Set where

data Set x where
    EmptySet :: Set a
    Insert :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Set a

instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
    show EmptySet = "{}"
    show xs = "{" ++ show' xs ++ "}"
      where
        show' (Insert a EmptySet) = show a
        show' (Insert a ys) = show a ++ ", " ++ show' ys

instance Eq (Set a) where
    (Insert x xs) == (Insert y ys) = x == y && xs == ys
    EmptySet == EmptySet = True
    _ == _ = False

memberSet :: a -> Set a -> Bool
memberSet x (Insert y ys) = x == y || memberSet x ys
memberSet _ _ = False

subSet :: Set a -> Set a -> Bool
subSet EmptySet _ = True
subSet (Insert a as) bs
    | memberSet a bs = subSet as bs
    | otherwise = False
```

By putting the `Eq` constraint on the `Insert` constructor of the type, we can ensure that

1. No nonempty set can be constructed for types not in `Eq`.
2. The `Eq` context (and dictionary) is available whenever we pattern-match on the `Insert` constructor, so we don't need to mention it in the function's type signature.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea you could do that... So, do I not have to declare type constructors when I do this?

Comment: Do You mean 'do I not have to declare type classes' there, instead of 'type constructors'? If so, the constraints you put on a value constructor in a `GADT` are available when pattern-matching on that constructor, so they need not be repeated in the function's type signature. Other constraints have of course to be given in the signature. Be aware, however, that the context is only available upon _pattern matching_, not everywhere where you use values of the type.

Comment: @Josh: If you're wondering about data constructors like `Insert` and `EmptySet`, those are still there. This is just an alternate syntax for defining them.

Comment: C. A. McCann. Thanks. That's what I was wondering. So essentially, this allows pattern matching on the input of the Type constructor?